# Modelsim Error: Failure while reading map channel

Tags: verilog, modelsim

I have a verilog code which compiles well. When I open the simulation file (.wlf) with vsim I get the following error:

My transcript says the following

OpenFile vsim.wlf
WLF Warning: Failure while reading map channel.
** Note: (vish-4074) File vsim.wlf is still open, viewing file in live viewing mode.
WLF file vsim.wlf contains no context information.

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Are you opening the wlf file for a simulation in progress or a completed simulation?  This looks like the message one would receive when trying to view a corrupted wlf file or one that does not yet have any data.

Comment: No.In fact I deleted all the associated files and built everything again. It still gives me the same error. By the way what does **Failure while reading map channel** mean ?

Answer (score -2):

Actually, I don't use the wlf file. So, I don't understand why you need to open the wlf file.

Wouldn't it be enough to look at some signals in the wave window?